# How to avoid dictionary's re-arrangement of key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create dictionary but the key are always re-arranged. I wanted the key to be arranged in appropriate order. Is it possible in python?

```
#!/bin/python

my_val = ["vel", "acc", "force"]

my_dict=dict()
for v in my_val:
  my_dict[v] = []

for l in my_val:
  print("l = ", l) 

print("dict re-arranges")
for key in my_dict:
  print("key = ", key)
```

> ```
> l =  vel
> l =  acc
> l =  force
> dict re-arranges
> key =  force
> key =  acc
> key =  vel
> ```

Comment: Use Python 3.7+, or use a `collections.OrderedDict` in older Python versions.

Comment: Relevant SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6